# Interleaving/multiplexing compressed streams

Tags: algorithm, stream, compression, deflate, lzw

I'm looking for a good compression algorithm or library that will let me interleave several compressed streams of data into a single stream of data, **without performance or compression loss**.

More context: I have been working on a compression format dedicated to a specific application. This compression format performs a bunch of domain-specific analysis on the data, then outputs the compressed data as a bunch of streams, each of which is compressed (typically with LZW, but that's not written in stone). One of these streams, the **primary stream**, contains a bunch of **tokens**. Each token from the primary stream contains the information I need to deduce which of the secondary streams contains my next **token**, how many decompressed bytes I need to read from that secondary stream, and what I need to do with this token.

So far, so good, but I don't want to ship my final data as a bunch of concatenated streams, because that would require me to receive the entire data before I can process it meaningfully. Rather, I'd like to ship them as a single stream, that I could decode and process as I receive it. So this would basically like to send something along the lines of:

- one token from the primary stream (compressed with the dictionary used for the primary stream);

  - ok, this is token "FooBar", I know that a token "FooBar" is always followed by two tokens from stream "Foo", one token from stream "Bar";
- two tokens from stream "Foo" (compressed with the dictionary used for stream "Foo");
- one token from stream "Bar" (compressed with the dictionary used for stream "Bar");
- one token from the primary stream (back to the compression of the primary stream);
- ...

The complication here is that any interesting compression algorithm isn't going to trivially translate one token to one or more bytes with a well-defined token end. Sometimes, it's going to be several packets for a single token. Sometimes, one packet will contain many tokens. Luckily for me, the size of my tokens is easy to predict. On the other hand, for space efficiency, I can't afford to write the size of each packet or the number of packets whenever I add one.

So, how can I multiplex/interleave all my compressed streams into a single stream without needing to add lots of metadata? My impression is that this is basically the kind of issues solved by multimedia formats, but I have zero domain knowledge on the topic. Any suggestion? I'm interested in algorithms, libraries and papers.

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this on your own instead of using a dedicated solution like Kafka ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How is this related to Kafka?

Comment: Kafka will allow you to abstract the compression method from the data you are using. It also allows you to use a wide range of compression methods. Snappy is the default but there has been a lot of focus on Zstandard. Maybe I am misunderstanding what you mean by a stream.

Comment: Can you serialize your custom data and streams into a single stream of bytes? Then, you can run a general purpose compressor on that stream. This eliminates one of the problems that you spoke of, namely the fact that compression algorithms do not output data that can be separated on byte boundaries.

Comment: @usr, well, that is exactly my problem. So no, I don't have a good way to do this without destroying compression :)

Comment: Can you buffer the contents of all streams and when the buffers are full you flush the secondary streams first, then the primary stream? That way there's only a need for one piece of meta data for each fairly large chunk of actual data. You would still need to invent a framing format but that can be very simple and small. The stream is a series of chunks. Each chunk is `stream-ID, length, data`.

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins I'm not too familiar with Kafka, but I guess I kind of see how a small subset of Kafka could be used to possibly solve a similar problem. I'm in a single producer, multiple consumer setting, with no stream processing in the middle, so Kafka looks like overkill. Plus, I definitely could not add a dependency towards Kafka. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: @usr Yes, that's one of the things I have in mind. I don't know yet how to insert synchronization points in my compressed streams, though. i.e. assuming that I compress with LZW, when do I know that the output stream produced by the compressor contains a specific set of bytes that I have fed it and that it's not stuck in the buffer? Now, maybe LZW is not the right format for that.

Comment: LZW? LZW is obsolete. Look at lz4, zlib or zstd, and lzma2, depending on where you would like the execution time / compression ratio trade to fall.

Comment: I believe you do not have to be concerned with compression at all. This is what I tried to say in my first comment. Imagine if you had a custom streaming format that worked both for sending and receiving like you want it. If you simply do not compress this stream then your app would work albeit at low efficiency. You now layer a general purpose streaming compression algorithm ontop but this does not give you additional problems. The sender first serializes, then pushes into the stream. The receiver simply pulls from the stream and deserializes that. Can you detail why this would not work?

Comment: In other words why do you need "synchronization points" at all, in your mind?

Comment: @Mark Adler Fine by me. Does any of these algorithms give me a synchronization point? i.e. a way to say "I gave you n bytes, I'm going to give you more, but please tell me once the compressed version of these n bytes is available in your output stream"

Comment: @usr In my example above with "FooBar", what would the packet contain?

Comment: The example is for a single primary token and does not make sense for my proposal. You should compress many items at once (e.g. 1000). So you generate 3 streams (primary, foo, bar) with the contents of 1000 items compressed. Then, you push those streams out over the wire one after the other. (I think you would call this a packet.) The metadata overhead is low because of the batching.

Comment: Yes, you can get synchronization points, but to get the best compression you want those to arise naturally as opposed to forcing them. You can force them if you like (there are options for that in zlib), but if you do that often, you will degrade compression.

Comment: @Mark Adler I can imagine that! Well, I have no problem with waiting for them. Thanks, I'll look for that in the documentation!

Comment: @usr Well, a synchronization point is what lets you find out that you have indeed finished compressing these 1000 items. Because when you put 1000 items in a stream, you may only end up with enough bytes to decompress 998 of them. The following 2 items are not sufficient to fill one byte (for instance), or the compression algorithm is expecting more data before it produces the bytes you need to decompress the last 2 items.

Comment: So you have a requirement to be able to process incoming data immediately? This was new to me. I thought this was about streaming data as opposed to needlessly buffering huge amounts of data.

Comment: @usr Ah, got it. You wanted to move buffering from the producer to the consumer. I wanted to process the stream immediately, as you point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With, for example, zlib, you can have three instances of deflate running at the same time for your three streams. With deflate you can compress a deflate block at a time (using Z_BLOCK), and bring that to a byte boundary with an empty stored block using Z_SYNC_FLUSH. You can interleave these deflate blocks as they are produced with a one-byte header for each identifying which of the three streams it is from. Then your decompressor reads in these deflate blocks and decompresses them with three instances of inflate, pulling your tokens from the respective blocks of uncompressed data as it becomes available.

Comment: `Z_SYNC_FLUSH` will waste space, right? Can I easily get a bitstream for zlib?

Also, since I have you at hand, would you suggest using zlib these days? I seem to have heard that you know a thing or two about zlib :)

Comment: Only four or five bytes. zlib may be good for your application, because it provides the sort of block-level control you need.